# How to Install Transiesta

Tags: software-installation

I am a new user of siesta and such stuff can anyone tell me how to install Tran siesta knowing that I already have siesta on my laptop.

SIESTA is computer program implementation that help in performing efficient electronic structure calculations and ab-nitio molecular dynamics simulations of molecules and solids. TranSiesta is a part of siesta that can help us in computing the electronic transport properties usually used in case of an open system formed by a finite structure sandwiched between two semi-infinite metallic leads.

I installed siesta and i was able to compute and obtain band strucures, density of state and such properties of my system. My second step is to study spin transport inside my system.. so that I have to use tran-siesta.. but still unable to install it.

Comment: By the way what is Siesta? What is Tran-Siesta? Where did you get first? Where you plan to get second?

Comment: SIESTA is  computer program implementation that help in performing efficient electronic structure calculations and ab-nitio molecular dynamics simulations of molecules and solids. TranSiesta is a part of siesta that can help us in computing the electronic transport properties usually used in case of an open system
formed by a finite structure sandwiched between two semi-infinite metallic leads.

Comment: I installed siesta and i was able to compute and obtain band strucures, density of state and such properties of my system. My second step is to study spin transport inside my system.. so that I have to use tran-siesta.. but still unable to install it.

Comment: Ok. Then how did you installed SIESTA? From which deb-package? Did you compiled it from some repository? Where this repository was located? What is your Ubuntu version? What are the errors?

Answer (score 0):

In the source code of Siesta [developers](https://launchpad.net/siesta) have the file named *README_TRANSIESTA* with [contents](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~siesta-ts/siesta/trunk_ts_soc/view/head:/README_TRANSIESTA):

> TranSiesta is now part of the distribution.
>   See the manual in Docs/siesta.tex for information.

The file above is [dated 2009-08-30 16:56:56 UTC](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~siesta-ts/siesta/trunk_ts_soc/revision/295.1.2). The [documentation](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~siesta-ts/siesta/trunk_ts_soc/view/head:/Docs/siesta.tex#L376) says:

> Starting from version 3.0, **siesta** includes the **TranSIESTA** module.

Also developers note in [*RELEASE_NOTES*](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~siesta-ts/siesta/trunk_ts_soc/view/head:/RELEASE_NOTES):

> Backward-compatibility issues
>
> - The `transiesta` executable has been deprecated. Please use
>      `siesta --electrode` 
>     for electrode calculations. For regular `transiesta` runs, there
>     is no need for the specific executable. Details were given in the
>     4.1-b4 release.

So it looks like you already have the needed component installed if get newest source from https://gitlab.com/siesta-project/siesta .

Comment: Thanks for your help.